# npm- Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...serify":"latest","cha'

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

Yesterday I uninstalled `angular-cli` to update to `@angular/cli` . But while trying to install  `@angular/cli`, I'm getting this error:

> Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...serify":"latest","cha'

I've tried cleaning cache with `npm cache verify --force`, but the error is same always.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

In you `package.json`, you might have set some 'latest' for some npm package that may not support the latest. try using '*' or `>=x.y.z` versions for it. the package name ends with `serify` (as seen in the error message)

Comment: It just worked this morning... I was trying to install `@angular/cli` globally. I think there was a network problem which showed those errors. But now it has been installed and it's working. Thanx for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Just a shift from npm to yarn solved&worked for me! 
simply `npm install -g yarn`... this doesn't give that end of json##